# Formatting Issues regarding geom_line and facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, facet

First time asking a question on this site.

I'm trying to format some of my facetted graphs, although I'm having trouble in doing so.

[image]

I'd like to remove the gray shading on all 3 graph titles, put a broken red vertical line at "classes start" and "home game", and transform the yscale in the "United States" graph to numeric format.

Here is what I have so far. I've attached a link to an image of my current graph below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
install_github("ochyzh/classdata")
library(classdata)
library(zoo)
data("covid_daily")
covid_daily$date1 <- ymd(covid_daily$date)

johnson<-covid_daily %>% filter(county %in% c("Johnson County"), state_name %in% c("Iowa")) %>% mutate(land="Johnson County", mean_cases7=zoo::rollmean(new_confirmed,k=7, fill=NA)) %>% select(mean_cases7, date1, land)

covid_daily$date1<-ymd(covid_daily$date)                                                  
iowa<-covid_daily %>% filter(state_name %in% c("Iowa")) %>% group_by(state_name, date1) %>% summarise(sum_cases=sum(new_confirmed, na.rm=TRUE),.groups="keep") %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(land="State of Iowa", mean_cases7=zoo::rollmean(sum_cases,k=7, fill=NA)) %>% select(mean_cases7, date1, land)
                                                                                                                  
unitedstates<-covid_daily %>% group_by(date1) %>% summarise(sum_cases=sum(new_confirmed, na.rm=TRUE),.groups="keep") %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(land="United States", mean_cases7=zoo::rollmean(sum_cases,k=7, fill=NA)) %>% ungroup() %>% select(mean_cases7, date1, land)

consolidated<-rbind(johnson,iowa,unitedstates)
  
ggplot(data=consolidated, aes(x=date1, y=mean_cases7))+geom_line()+facet_wrap(~land, nrow=3, scale="free")+labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)+scale_x_date(, breaks=c(as.Date("2020-08-24"), as.Date("2020-10-31")), lab = c("U of I\nClasses Start", "Hawkeyes\nHome Game"))+theme_bw()+theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'))+theme(panel.border = element_blank())
```

Comment: What package does the "covid_daily" data come from? Its easier to help you when we can copy/paste the code to run it.

Comment: Try `theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))`, add `+ scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)` and `+ geom_vline(xintercept = as.Date("2020-08-24"), color = "red")` and  `+ geom_vline(xintercept = as.Date("2020-10-31"), color = "red")` . I don't have your data, so can't test any of these. Perhaps try adding one at a time to your plot and seeing if they give the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks all for your help! Allan's response solved it! I amended the code above in order to show where I got my data package from.